# Does tap gestures added to cell gets preserved on reuse?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell with an image. I am adding tap gesture to it tableview delegate method. When the cell gets reused, does the tap gesture duplicated? What happens to the tap gesture?

```
class CalendarCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var locationImageView: UIImageView!
}

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell") as! CalendarCell
        let locationLabelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(locationDidTap(recognizer:)))
        cell.locationLabel.addGestureRecognizer(locationLabelTap)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func locationDidTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That locationLabelTap gesture is added to every cell of a label, when a user is going to tap on a label of every cell then locationDidTap will get called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

---

Long answer:

You shouldn't be doing it like that. Add the tap gesture when the cell is initialized. This way the tap is added only once when it is created and not everytime it is reused.

```
class CalendarCell: UITableViewCell {

    //Your variable declaration and other stuff
    .
    .
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        //Adding subviews, constraints and other stuff
        .
        .
        .
        let locationLabelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(locationDidTap(recognizer:)))
        locationLabel.addGestureRecognizer(locationLabelTap)
    }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

If you are using a storyboard, you should do the same in `awakeFromNib` file as pointed out by [@DuncanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c).

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    .
    .
    .
    let locationLabelTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(locationDidTap(recognizer:)))
    locationLabel.addGestureRecognizer(locationLabelTap)
}
```

Comment: I agree with your statement that the gesture recognizer should only be added once the lifecycle of a cell, but the code you posted won’t work. In initial the cells views won’t have been created. You need to attach the gesture recognizer in awakeFromNib()

Comment: @DuncanC isn’t that for when you use a storyboard setup?

Comment: `awakeFromNib()` gets called when a view gets un-archived from a nibfile. (Storyboards use nibfiles internally, so it still gets called.) It is **possible** to create the a cell's view layout in code, but the cell's subviews are almost always defined in either an XIB (nib) or in a storyboard.

Comment: The fact is that in a view's init method, it's subviews have not been created yet, so your code is certain to fail. In fact it will probably crash, since the view's outlets are probably implicitly unwrapped optionals and when you try to reference an implicitly unwrapped optional that is nil, you crash.

Comment: @DuncanC i do not understand. I’ve always defined the subviews inside the cell class as lazy variables. Are you saying there is a better way?

Comment: The tap works when added inside `awakeFromNib()` only. It is not working in `init()`

Comment: @jsloop It works for me. Are you using storyboard or xib?

Comment: I am using storyboard.

Comment: @jsloop i have included the required answer. I do not work with storyboards. This is how i usually do it.